# Run CLI command from BashOperator in Kubernete

Tags: bash, kubernetes, command-line-interface, airflow

We moved our airflow architecture from Celery to Kubernete Executor.

I was using bash command to run next dag when the previous one in main chain was finished with:

```
my_task_1 = bash.BashOperator(
task_id="my_task_1",
dag=dag,
bash_command='airflow dags trigger dag_2_id'
)
```

But sadly I cant figure out how to run CLI commands from the inside of Kubernetes.
Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Do you have some errors / logs?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simply to use TriggerDagRunOperator instead of doing it with some bash commands.